# How to scrape script data using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from a script. First I use **soup.find_all** then convert it using **js2py** and finally print the desired data. but it didn't work. I want to know how can I collect **soldNum** information?

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import js2py

html_text = requests.get('https://www.daraz.com.bd/womens-shalwar-kameez/?spm=a2a0e.home.cate_1_1.2.735212f7tVtHu9&price=600-&from=filter').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
# Find the div with the specific attribute
script_content = soup.find_all('script')[3]
for script in script_content:
    f = js2py.eval_js(script)
    print(f)
    soldNum = f['soldNum']
    print(soldNum)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this using regular expressions (re module) to search for the soldNum data within the script contents

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import json

# Fetch the page content
url = 'https://www.daraz.com.bd/womens-shalwar-kameez/?spm=a2a0e.home.cate_1_1.2.735212f7tVtHu9&price=600-&from=filter'
html_text = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')

# Use regular expressions to find patterns that might hold the soldNum data
pattern = re.compile(r'\"soldNum\":\d+')

# Iterate through script tags and search for the pattern
for script in soup.find_all('script'):
    if script.string:  # Only proceed if the script tag contains text
        matches = pattern.findall(script.string)
        if matches:
            # Assuming you've found matches, you can then parse those
            for match in matches:
                # Extracting the numerical value
                soldNum = json.loads('{' + match + '}')
                print(soldNum['soldNum'])
```

## Note: This is a simplified example and might need adjustments based on the actual script contents.

Comment: it does not match and prints empty  ` print(soldNum['soldNum'])`  but the script has 60 sold number information.